# Capturar clique com Jquery e adicionar css

Tags: jquery, css

Sou iniciante em Jquery e possuo a seguinte dúvida. 
Possuo uma `div` e uma `ul` com várias `li`.

A `ul` está como `display:none`, quero acionar `display:block` quando eu clicar na div. Conforme abaixo:

```
   <div class="divTitulo">Residencial</div>
   <ul class="ulDisplayNone">
      <li class="liDisplayNone">item1</li>
      <li class="liDisplayNone">item1</li>
      <li class="liDisplayNone">item1</li>
      <li class="liDisplayNone">item1</li>
      <li class="liDisplayNone">item1</li>
      <li class="liDisplayNone">item1</li>
      <li class="liDisplayNone">item1</li>
   </ul>
```

O script que fiz, ficou assim:

```
<script>
  $( ".divTitulo" ).click(function() {
     $(".ulDisplayNone").css("display:block");
  });
  </script>
```

Não está funcionando, o que fiz de errado?

Mas, como faço para esconder a div que ativei?

Tentei

```
else
$(this).next('ul').hide();
```

Não sei se a sintaxe está correta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrigir para:

```
$(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").css("display", "block");
```

O primeiro parâmetro é a propriedade e o segundo é o valor, porém também pode passar um objeto literal para editar mais de uma propriedado com apenas uma chamada:

```
$(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").css({display: "block"});
```

Ou:

```
$(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").show();
```

Caso queira melhorar o seu script pode substituir por:

```
$(this).next('ul').show();
```

Assim você evita mais uma classe e pode reaproveitar o script.

O script completo da forma que vejo como melhor ficaria próximo disso:

```
$('.divTitulo').on('click', function() {

    $(this).next('ul').show();

});
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Uma dúvida um tanto quanto iniciante. Esse script eu coloco antes da div e ul? ou pode ser depois mesmo?
Seria isso o correto?<script>   $(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").css({"display", "block"});                    
});</script>

Comment: Vou editar a resposta com a forma inteira de como ficaria.

Comment: Melhor cara, fiz no JSFiddle, se puder olhar:
http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/5DfWU/

Comment: Na verdade assim: http://jsfiddle.net/5DfWU/4/

Comment: Você modificou apenas o `script`?

Comment: Não, eu retirei um display node onde não precisava...

Comment: Valeu Diego, funcionou 100% :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso de varias maneiras
uma delas é da forma abaixo:

sem efeito:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".divTitulo" ).click(function() {
        $(".ulDisplayNone").toggle();
    });
})
```

Com efeito slide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".divTitulo" ).click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    });
})
```

Com efeito fade:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".divTitulo" ).click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').fadeToggle();
    });
})
```

**Dessa forma você irá exibir com o primeiro clique e ocultar com um segundo clique**

Answer (score 0):

A forma correta de usar CSS no jQuery é `$(".ulDisplayNone").css("display", "block");`